# Virtual event conference and networking platform recommendation

Tags: authentication

Looking for virtual event conference and networking platform (such as Remo) that easily integrates with Drupal/CIVICRM for authentication and online profile access.

Comment: you may need to spell out the features you are specifically looking for. i just googled Remo and it sounds like Zoom offers much of what is required, and there is existing integration for Zoom. I have never heard Remo mentioned in the civi community before